# Logarithmic Equation: How to solve for x

Tags: logarithms

Equation: $$\log_a (x) + \log_a (x-4) = \log_a (x+6)$$

**Progress**

$$\log_a (x^2-4x) = \log_a (x+6)$$
$$x^2-5x-6=0$$

**Delta**

$$x1= 6$$

$$x2=-1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is correct. Now, if you search only real solutions, you have
$$
x^2-4x=x+6
$$
can you solve? (be care to the the acceptability of the solutions).

Comment: I used delta, therfore: **x1= 6, x2=-1**

Comment: well. Now you have to verify that the $\log$ are defined . i.e. $x>0$, $x-4>0$ and $x+6>0$. So the solution is $x=6$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\log_a X = \log_a Y$$ implies $$X=Y$$

So in your case, you need to solve an equation.